# Application pool in IIS 7 does not show .NET Framework 3.5

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I've .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 installed on my system.
When I create a new application pool, I just see the .NET Framework V2.0.xxx.
I've a file that uses the ASP.NET MVC. It's not loading. I think this might be the reason.

Comment: A similar question for .NET Framework 4.5: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559372/how-to-set-net-framework-4-5-version-in-iis-7-application-pool

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Scott Hanselman's ComputerZen.com - How to set an IIS Application or AppPool to use ASP.NET 3.5 rather than 2.0](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToSetAnIISApplicationOrAppPoolToUseASPNET35RatherThan20.aspx)

Answer (score 21):

I think rather confusingly it's referring to the .Net Runtime version, which for .Net 3.5 framework is still Runtime version 2.0.

You can google for explanations for this but it's along the lines of.

- .Net 2.0 Framework -- .Net 2.0 Runtime
- .Net 3.0 Framework -- .Net 2.0 Runtime
- .Net 3.5 Framework -- .Net 2.0 Runtime
- .Net 3.5 Sp1       -- .Net 2.0 Runtime
- .Net 4.0 Framework -- .Net 4.0 Runtime

I've noticed that MVC sometimes has problems if it's not run using the "Integrated" Managed Pipeline Mode, so might want to try that.

Comment: I think you'll find that there is no .NET 3.0 Runtime. I'm pretty sure .NET 4 comes with the .NET 4 runtime.

Comment: Corrected as per your comment... makes you wonder though what happened to the .Net 3.0 runtime?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what exactly the question is, if you expecting framework 3.5 in IIS don't.
The two frameworks in IIS are 1.1 and 2.0. So framework 3.5 will still only show 2.0 in IIS

Answer (score 2):

As was explained earlier, .NET 3.0 and 3.5 built on top of .NET 2.0, so there was no need for those choices. Now that .NET 4.0 is out, it does include an entry for ASP.NET 4.0 as it includes a new runtime.

As such, your possible choices now include:
1.1.4322  (.NET 1.1)
2.0.50727 (.NET 2.0, 3.0, 3.5)
4.0.30319 (.NET 4.0)

Answer (score 1):

.NET 3.0 and .NET 3.5 are additions to .NET 2.0, the core runtime is still the same, so you will not see 3.5 in the application pool settings. The problem may lie elsewhere.

You might try re-registering the 3.0 mappings though, by running servicemodelreg in the 3.0\Windows Communication Foundation directory, but that will only fix problems with WCF

Answer (score 1):

The question here is that after .NET Framework 2.0 all other versions of it were incremental, not a new implementation.

That's why IIS reports only .NET 2.0.