# error MSB4019: Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, msbuild

I created a project using Visual Studio 2010 and trying to create the build in TFS 2013. I am getting the following error. Target Framework is 4.0. Why my build server is looking for Visual Studio 12.0 folder? How to change this settings? I appreciate any suggestions.

```
error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found
```

Comment: Where are you getting this error? Locally or on the build server?

Comment: It's on the Build Server. I installed VS 2010 on build server.

Comment: Have you had a look at the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002532/build-vs2013-on-a-tfs-build-server-with-only-vs2013

Comment: Thank you. I changed the MSBuild configuration to use Visual Studio 2010. It works now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Microsoft.WebApplication.targets was not found, on the build server. What's your solution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980909/microsoft-webapplication-targets-was-not-found-on-the-build-server-whats-your)

Comment: possible duplicate of [External VS2013 build error "error MSB4019: The imported project <path> was not found"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718281/external-vs2013-build-error-error-msb4019-the-imported-project-path-was-not)

Answer (score 1):

Copy the directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0" from development machine to the build machine.

http://howtoscript.blogspot.com.tr/2014/05/error-msb4019-imported-project-cprogram.html?view=magazine

Answer (score 0):

You need to do one of the following:

1. Change the build configuration to use 2010
2. Install VS 2013 on the build server.

I would recommend upgrading your visual studio anyway as you are already 2 versions behind with CTP's already available for DEV14,..