# External VS2013 build error “error MSB4019: The imported project <path> was not found”

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, build, msbuild

I building a project from a command proms using CMake file.
The project can be found [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/xmp.html).

On the build I have the following error:

```
"C:\Users\User\Desktop\XMP-Toolkit-SDK-CC201306\build\vc10\static\windows_x64\CMakeFiles\3.0.0\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.Redirect.props(44,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.Redirect.10.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. [C:\Users\User\Desktop\XMP-Toolkit-SDK-CC201306\build\vc10\static\windows_x64\CMakeFiles\3.0.0\CompilerIdC\CompilerIdC.vcxproj]
```

I know that it should be because the project is in Visual Studio 2010 and I am executing for Visual Studi 2013.

I saw some answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718281/external-vs2013-build-error-error-msb4019-the-imported-project-path-was-not), but they don't fit my case. I don't have .csproj file and when running

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\amd64>MSBuild.exe <project or solution t
o build> /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0
```

I see only

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Any ideas?

THANKS!

**

- UPDATE

Using the archive provided by Maskim, the build skipped the error, but instead provided new errors. I am pasting almost the end of the cmd process below:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\XMP-Toolkit-SDK-CC201306\build>echo "================= Gen
erate project for XMP build ================="
"================= Generate project for XMP build ================="

C:\Users\User\Desktop\XMP-Toolkit-SDK-CC201306\build>call cmake.bat 64 2013 Warn
ingAsError Static

C:\Users\User\Desktop\XMP-Toolkit-SDK-CC201306\build>echo OFF
64 bit specified
"Generator VS 2013 specified"
"sensible warnings activated"
"Static build on"
CMakeFolder: "vc13/static/windows_x64"
Generator used: Visual Studio 12 Win64
cmake ../../../. -G"Visual Studio 12 Win64" -DXMP_CMAKEFOLDER_NAME=""vc13/static
/windows_x64"" -DCMAKE_CL_64=ON -DCMAKE_ARCH=x64 -DXMP_BUILD_WARNING_AS_ERROR=On
 -DXMP_BUILD_STATIC="On"
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.31101.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.31101.0
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64 -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64 -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
COMMON_BUILD_SHARED_DIR= C:/Users/User/Desktop/XMP-Toolkit-SDK-CC201306/build/..
/build/shared
CMake Error: Error in cmake code at
C:/Users/User/Desktop/XMP-Toolkit-SDK-CC201306/XMPCore/build/CMakeLists.txt:170:

Parse error.  Function missing ending ")".  Instead found bad character with tex
t "[".
CMake Error: Error in cmake code at
C:/Users/User/Desktop/XMP-Toolkit-SDK-CC201306/XMPFiles/build/CMakeLists.txt:284
:
Parse error.  Function missing ending ")".  Instead found bad character with tex
t "[".
-- ===========================================================================
--  XMPToolkitSDK
-- ===========================================================================
--  64 bit build is: 1
--  Static build is: On
--  XMPToolkitSDK
--
--
--  Compiler:
--  CC=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.e
xe
--  CXX=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.
exe
-- ===========================================================================
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/User/Desktop/XMP-Toolkit-SDK-CC201306/build/vc13/static/windo
ws_x64/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Failed XMP build cmake.
"Exiting CMakeUtils.bat"
Failed  build cmake.
"Exiting cmake.bat"
Failed.
"Exiting cmake_all.bat"
CMake Build Failed.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**

Comment: A .csproj file is only for C# projects, use the .vcxproj file that you have.

Comment: I don't have a project. I am trying to generate it.

Comment: CompilerIdC.vcxproj is a project.  Use the Visual Studio Command Prompt to run msbuild.

Comment: @HansPassant CompilerIdC.vcxproj is generated only after I try to parse the project and it fails. I do it using VS Command Prompt,maybe I do something wrong? What shall be the location and the exact command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now problem us unclear for me, its building ok on my PC with VS2013, may be more simply path for build, like c:\dev\XMP...
My log :

```
c:\dev\XMP-Toolkit-SDK-CC201306\build>echo "================= Generate project f
or XMP build ================="
"================= Generate project for XMP build ================="

c:\dev\XMP-Toolkit-SDK-CC201306\build>call cmake.bat 64 2013 WarningAsError Stat
ic

c:\dev\XMP-Toolkit-SDK-CC201306\build>echo OFF
64 bit specified
"Generator VS 2013 specified"
"sensible warnings activated"
"Static build on"
CMakeFolder: "vc13/static/windows_x64"
Generator used: Visual Studio 12 Win64
cmake ../../../. -G"Visual Studio 12 Win64" -DXMP_CMAKEFOLDER_NAME=""vc13/static
/windows_x64"" -DCMAKE_CL_64=ON -DCMAKE_ARCH=x64 -DXMP_BUILD_WARNING_AS_ERROR=On
 -DXMP_BUILD_STATIC="On"
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.30723.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 18.0.30723.0
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64 -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64 -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
COMMON_BUILD_SHARED_DIR= C:/dev/XMP-Toolkit-SDK-CC201306/build/../build/shared
-- ===========================================================================
--  XMPCore64
-- ===========================================================================
--  OUTPUT_DIR = C:/dev/XMP-Toolkit-SDK-CC201306/XMPCore/build/../../public/libr
aries/windows_x64/$(configuration)
-- ===========================================================================
--  XMPFiles64
-- ===========================================================================
--  OUTPUT_DIR = C:/dev/XMP-Toolkit-SDK-CC201306/XMPFiles/build/../../public/lib
raries/windows_x64/$(configuration)
-- ===========================================================================
--  XMPToolkitSDK
-- ===========================================================================
--  64 bit build is: 1
--  Static build is: On
--  XMPToolkitSDK
--
--
--  Compiler:
--  CC=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.e
xe
--  CXX=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.
exe
-- ===========================================================================
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    CMAKE_ARCH
    XMP_BUILD_WARNING_AS_ERROR


-- Build files have been written to: C:/dev/XMP-Toolkit-SDK-CC201306/build/vc13/
static/windows_x64
Success XMP build cmake.
"Exiting CMakeUtils.bat"
Success  build cmake.
"Exiting cmake.bat"
Success.
"Exiting cmake_all.bat"
CMake Build Success.
```

Comment: Hm...weird. I added it to the same location as your's is..but am still having the issue? Can it be forced by another files?

Comment: Can you please .rar or .zip your the XMP-Toolkit-SDK-CC201306 folder and share it with me, so I can download it?

Comment: can you just e-mail me or share on OneDrive/DropBox, or whatever fits you more?

Comment: ok already generated files for VS2013, tested in DEBUG - solution builded: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f4pcul4qs0akdbf/XMP-Toolkit-SDK-CC201306.zip?dl=0

Comment: I see you are aware of XMP and want to ask you some more questions if you don't mind. Can I have you skypename?

Comment: Or may you add me - megibyan ?

Answer (score 1):

did you saw "cmake fail" when builded ? 
are you thinking it's ok ? 
here fixed files for VS2013 : http://amv007.zz.mu/temp/build.zip

Comment: copy files from archive to build folder, and run generateXMP, it now must support Visual Studio 2013

Comment: It helped somehow, but now it generate another errors. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Now I don't know what the problem, may be try move to more simply directory, like c:\dev\XMP...<br>