# ASP.Net Core Web API Build Error - MSB4019 The imported project Microsoft.DotNet.Props was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import>

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am getting the following error in my **ASP.Net Core Web API Project**, after I added **Sqlite Reference** (see below) and also changed the `Microsoft.NETCore.App` dependency version in `project.json` from `1.0.1` (which was working) to `1.1.0` (which is breaking the build with the following error).

> **Error   MSB4019**   The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.1\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" was not found. **Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk**.    Cities.API  C:\Shiva\PluralSight\Cities.API\Cities.API.xproj    8

Please don't mark this as duplicate of either

1. [External VS2013 build error “error MSB4019: The imported project  was not found”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19718281/325521) or
2. [External VS2013 build error “error MSB4019: The imported project  was not found”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27378405/325521)

I looked at these 2 and they apply to Visual Studio 2013 and not the .Net Core version, which has a different project and config file structure.

Here's my `projects.json`

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "NLog.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rtm-alpha5",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Design": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0",
    "AutoMapper": "5.2.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

and here's the error message when I do a build with the new updated `1.1.0` for the `Microsoft.NETCore.App` dependency. NOTE: the `1.1.0` does show up in the intellisense dropdown when I did the beginning `"` which means that it is present on my machine.

[image]

#### Output of `dotnet --info`

[ Update 15.Mar.2017] Per @Leo-MSFT's request, here's the output of `dotnet --info`

[image]

Comment: Do you have two version of the CLI installed? Could you please provide the dotnet info to us? You can get that info by type “dotnet --info” on the Package Manager Console. What is the build  result if you create a new ASP.Net Core Web API Project without any modification?

Comment: Hi, 1) How to tell if I have 2 versions of CLI installed? 2) I've provided the dotnet info as an update (see the end of my question above). 3) I created a new ASP.Net Core Web API Project from scratch and that builds (no errors). The strangest thing is, I went back to a working version of the Project before adding sqlite or changing `Microsoft.Netcore.App` and even that project is popping up that error message as soon as I opened it in VS 2015. I can send you a zip of it if you like (it's a PluralSight walkthrough I wrote, so nothing confidential in code).

Comment: thanks for you reply. what is the build result after you change the sdk version to "1.0.0-preview2-003131" in the global.json? If sdk not found, please download from https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=830694 and install it, restart VS, then build it again. if not works, Please upload the file to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link here.

Comment: @ Shiva, what about this issue? Would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error (see this question: [Swagger-codegen: error building Pet Store example for .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45589890/swagger-codegen-error-building-pet-store-example-for-net-core))

The fix for me was to run `dotnet migrate` which updates the project to use a `.csproj` and moves the `.xproj` and `project.json` out of the way.

More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/migration/#dotnet-migrate

Answer (score 1):

For .Net Core , Same error code and I was not able to run ef commands in command line. Check this solutions, It works for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58024947/1415927

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in .NET6 project. But the simple PC restart, starting VS as admin and cleaning solution helped.

Error:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
> MSB4019 The imported project "C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.301\Sdk\AutoImport.props"
> was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration
> "C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.301\Sdk\AutoImport.props"
> is correct, and that the file exists on disk. SatisFIT.Server
> C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.ImportWorkloads.props
> 14