# Microsoft.dotnet.props was not found - Confirm that path in <import> declaration is correct

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I am trying to run dotnet core project I get error: `Microsoft.dotnet.props was not found`.

I have installed the dotnet core please check below screenshot.

I have seen other threads below but they are not working for me.

[Microsoft.DotNet.Props was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020289/microsoft-dotnet-props-was-not-found)

[ASP.Net Core Web API Build Error - MSB4019 The imported project Microsoft.DotNet.Props was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42800817/asp-net-core-web-api-build-error-msb4019-the-imported-project-microsoft-dotnet)

I am new to this; I have tried and read lots of issues on SO and git but I am not able to sort issue. Any help will be great.

Let me know if I need to add more details.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am wondering why you try to work with 1.0.1. There is 1.1 available now. I think theres a problem with the global.json File, where dotnetcore get the Properties by IOC for the solution.. Youve got this file? Try to download 1.1 .. https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core

Comment: I think I have tried as well... let me try it again... thanks Andrew :)

Comment: Installing this has fixed the issue.
https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/1.1-preview2.1-download.md