# Swagger-codegen: error building Pet Store example for .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, swagger-codegen

I am trying out [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) to generate the Pet Store example for .NET Core. When I try to build the project, I see this error:

```
/home/username/test/src/IO.Swagger/IO.Swagger.xproj(7,5): error MSB4019:
The imported project "/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.4/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v14.0/
DotNet/Microsoft.DotNet.Props"
was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct,
and that the file exists on disk.
```

The exact steps I ran were:

```
$ java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i 
     http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json -l aspnetcore -o test/
$ cd test/
$ chmod +x build.sh
$ ./build.sh
```

Versions:

```
$ dotnet --version
1.0.4
$ java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar version
2.2.3
```

It looks like the generated .NET core project is not compatible with the version of .NET core I am using. How can I easily update the generated project so it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer after reading this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/migration/#dotnet-migrate

The answer is to run `dotnet migrate` in the directory containing the `.xproj`. This creates a `.csproj` which can be built without errors.