# Unable to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an MSBuild-based .NET Core project

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-database-first, entity-framework-core-2.1

I've been researching a lot online but did not find a proper solution. I was trying to use Entity Framework Core with MySQL by using database-first scaffold method to mapping table model while always received this error when applied the command

```
Unable to retrieve project metadata. Ensure it's an MSBuild-based .NET Core project. If you're using custom BaseIntermediateOutputPath or MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath values, Use the --msbuildprojectextensionspath option.
```

This is the command I am using to scaffold the database model:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "server=localhost;port=3306;user=root;password=1234;database=world" "Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" -OutputDir .\Models -f
```

And this is my .Net Core project setting:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="2.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: any news on this?

Comment: To all future people having this issue. If you set the startup project, remember to take into account the folder. I was getting the same error because I specified "../Api.csproj" when it should have been "../Api/Api.csproj"

Answer (score 5):

#### For EF Core 3

I think the powershell command has gone away for EF Core 3 so I'm using `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold`

With this command, if you're converting a `Scaffold-DbContext` script the project name (parameter `--project`) needs to have `.csproj` on the end - it can't just the extensionless name.

Comment: In my case I lost 3 days in this ridiculous problem.

Comment: I was getting the error trying to run the command `dotnet-ef migrations add First --project DotNetCoreTest`. Adding the extension `.csproj` with the project name resolved the issue

Answer (score 3):

I got this error trying to add a new migration on the command line with `dotnet ef migrations add NewMigration`.

The solution for me was indeed to append `--msbuildprojectextentionspath obj/local`.

Comment: This worked for me as well because I was using the following to change the build properties:

<Project>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER)' != 'true'">
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/obj/local/</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    <BaseOutputPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/bin/local/</BaseOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

Answer (score 2):

For my case this error was solved by downloading latest [dotnet-sdk-2.2.107-win-x64](https://dotnet.microsoft.com//download/dotnet-core/2.2#sdk-2.2.107)

for VS2017 and then dropping and updating database through cmd:

```
dotnet ef database drop --force --context <<dbcontext>> -s <<startup project directory>> -p <<project directory>>


dotnet ef database update --context <<dbcontext>> -s <<startup project directory>> -p <<project directory>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here goes the definitively solution for this problem.

I work with Rider Ide constructing a Web Api, using Net core 3 with Pomelo.MySql

I have tree layers defining my application:

Test.Domain - Class Library defining my models
Test.Infra.DataAccess - Class library defining my DbContext
Test.Service.RestApi - Net Core Api Project, where I define the AppContext in Startup file. Like This:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContextPool<AerjDbContext>(
            options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySqlConnectionString"),
                mysqlOptions => mysqlOptions.ServerVersion(new Version(8,0,19), ServerType.MySql)
                    .EnableRetryOnFailure()
            ));
    }
```

This is quite normal, the magic occurs here:

Initiate migrations:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --startup-project "../<Here the name of the project where startup file was configured>"
```

It'll create the migrations

then we have to update database with sabe command structure;

```
dotnet ef database update --startup-project "../<Here the name of the project where startup file was configured>"
```

Comment: what type of project did you use for the one defining your DbContext? and which project folder did you run 'dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate'?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have tried  different solutions to solve this error. Did following change in .csproj file.

[image]

**Solved** this issue for .Net Core by edit .csproj file and removed Import tag and then run ef command again in command line.

Answer (score 0):

EF migrations with .NETCore 2.2 can be smoke-tested using `migrations list`:

```
dotnet ef migrations list --startup-project <app-startup-project-dir> --project <dal-project-dir> --context App.DAL.ApplicationDbContext
```

`--context` must point to the fully qualified name of the DbContext class that you want to manipulate.

Answer (score -5):

Add this parameter to the end of your scaffold command "--msbuildprojectextensionspath".