# Visual studio 2012 Imported project was not found

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

[image]

I'm trying to create new console project in my Visual Studio 2012. It gives me this error. After I click OK, it ends up I only have the .sln file, not even any .csproj file.

Steps:
 1. File -> New -> Project
 2. Fill the project name, project location path. Press OK
 3. Get this error
 4. Inside the project location path, there is only the .sln file and one empty folder.

I expect it to have at least generated .csproj, if there's anything wrong with the build, at least I can edit it in the .csproj file. But now nothing is generated, what is exactly wrong?

How to fix this?

Comment: Please describe your exact steps - your question is unclear at the moment. (You talk about it not creating a .csproj file, and then you ask about a file that *is* created...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [External VS2013 build error "error MSB4019: The imported project <path> was not found"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718281/external-vs2013-build-error-error-msb4019-the-imported-project-path-was-not)

Comment: File->New->Project, I filled in the project name, set the location to <\visual studio 2012\Projects> press OK, then I would get as per the screenshot. 

Inside the <\visual studio 2012\Projects> folder, there would exist only the .sln file and an empty folder (and nothing else).

Meanwhile, the error messagebox seems to indicate that it created the .csproj inside the Temp folder, or do I understand it wrongly?

The link that Bahman gave me all points to editing the .csproj file, but I don't even have any .csproj file created!