# Compilation of .NET 4.6 C# project without Visual Studio

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

I try to compile a .NET 4.6 C# project on my build machine using only MSBuild. I did not install the Visual Studio 2015 on the machine, but just the following:

- .NET Framework 4.6 Runtime
- .NET Framework Targeting Pack
- Microsoft Build Tools 2015

I run following in the cmd: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" MySolution.sln

The error I get is:

> "error MSB4019: The imported project
>   "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Defaults.props" was not found. Confirm that the path
>   in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on
>   disk."

I have already checked that the "Microsoft.Cpp.Defaults.props" file exists in "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0", but not in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140". Actually even the folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140" does not exist.

What more should I do/install to compile this?

Comment: It's probably the case that "the path in the declaration" is incorrect, since the pathname given in the error message puts the file in the root directory of the C: drive.

Comment: Please try uninstalling and reinstalling the build tools.  Seems this should fix this.  The default path is not properly set that cause the error.

Comment: I reinstalled the Build Tools, even installed them on the other machine and still there is the same error...

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem. I fixed it by adding below argument when run ms build.

```
/p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0
```

Not 14.0.

I refered this answer.

[External VS2013 build error "error MSB4019: The imported project <path> was not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718281/external-vs2013-build-error-error-msb4019-the-imported-project-path-was-not)