# error MSB4102: The value "" of the "Project" attribute in element <Import> is invalid. Parameter "path" cannot have zero length. F#

Tags: f#, teamcity, canopy-web-testing

I am getting following error while building project in Team city.

Same project is getting build on Local machine. Local machine has VS 2015 and F# 4.0.

My Project Configuration is as below.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />


    <Choose>
        <When Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '11.0'">
          <PropertyGroup Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\..\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets')">
            <FSharpTargetsPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\..\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
          </PropertyGroup>
        </When>
        <Otherwise>
          <PropertyGroup Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\FSharp\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets')">
            <FSharpTargetsPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\FSharp\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
          </PropertyGroup>
        </Otherwise>
      </Choose>
      <Import Project="$(FSharpTargetsPath)" />
```

This is Console application.

Comment: Issue was on the Agent which the Team city was using as reference for doing build.

That agent machine was not having some dependencies installed.

Like, F# 4.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [External VS2013 build error "error MSB4019: The imported project <path> was not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718281/external-vs2013-build-error-error-msb4019-the-imported-project-path-was-not)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar problem a while back, because I was running the local machine with Administrator privileges, but the Visual Studio installer had set environment variables at the `user` level and not the `system` level which Administrator uses. So when compiling as Administrator, the `FSharpTargetsPath` was not being correctly built from environment variables like `VisualStudioVersion`.

Have a look on your local machine to see what environment variables values are set for `VisualStudioVersion` at the level you are successfully using (System or User), as well as other variables and then check that these are set at the corresponding level on the Team City machine.

Perhaps you are running as `user` on your local machine and `System` on the Team City machine.

See details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21420306/152739

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Hi Scott, Thanks for quick reply!

Issue was on the Agent which the Team city was using as reference for doing build.

That agent machine was not having some dependencies installed.

Like, F# 4.0

Comment: How would someone confirm or change this?