# .Net Core & Jenkins CI Build

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, continuous-integration, .net-core

I have a .net application built on .net Core framework, I am trying to build this application on Jenkins CI server. I've added MSBuild plugin and have added path to the .exe file of MSBuild.

```
MSBuild Configuration 
MSBuild.exe : C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin

Project Build:
MSBuild Build File: ebookingV4.sln
Command Line Arguments: /p:VisualStudioVersion="14.0" /t:rebuild
```

But my building processes are failing by showing the below error message.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace>exit 0  Path To MSBuild.exe: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild.exe Executing the command cmd.exe /C " "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 /t:rebuild ebookingV4.sln " && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% from C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace [workspace] $ cmd.exe /C " "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 /t:rebuild ebookingV4.sln " && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% Microsoft (R) Build Engine, versi¢n 14.0.23107.0 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Todos los derechos reservados.

Los proyectos de esta soluci¢n se van a compilar de uno en uno. Para habilitar la compilaci¢n en paralelo, agregue el modificador "/m". Compilaci¢n iniciada a las 13/09/2016 10:53:05 a.m.. Proyecto "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" en el nodo 1 (rebuild destinos). ValidateSolutionConfiguration:   Compilando la configuraci¢n de soluciones "Debug|Any CPU". El proyecto "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (1) est  compilando "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\MongoRepository\MongoRepository.xproj" (2) en el nodo 1 (Rebuild destinos). C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\MongoRepository\MongoRepository.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco. Compilaci¢n del proyecto terminada "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\MongoRepository\MongoRepository.xproj" (Rebuild destinos) -- ERROR. El proyecto "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (1) est  compilando "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\MongoDomain\MongoDomain.xproj" (3) en el nodo 1 (Rebuild destinos). C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\MongoDomain\MongoDomain.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco. Compilaci¢n del proyecto terminada "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\MongoDomain\MongoDomain.xproj" (Rebuild destinos) -- ERROR. El proyecto "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (1) est  compilando "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\EBookingCoreNew\EBookingCoreNew.xproj" (4) en el nodo 1 (Rebuild destinos). C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\EBookingCoreNew\EBookingCoreNew.xproj(8,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco. Compilaci¢n del proyecto terminada "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\EBookingCoreNew\EBookingCoreNew.xproj" (Rebuild destinos) -- ERROR. El proyecto "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (1) est  compilando "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\NPSRepository\NPSRepository.xproj" (5) en el nodo 1 (Rebuild destinos). C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\NPSRepository\NPSRepository.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco. Compilaci¢n del proyecto terminada "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\NPSRepository\NPSRepository.xproj" (Rebuild destinos) -- ERROR. El proyecto "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (1) est  compilando "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\EBookingDomain\EBookingDomain.xproj" (6) en el nodo 1 (Rebuild destinos). C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\EBookingDomain\EBookingDomain.xproj(8,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco. Compilaci¢n del proyecto terminada "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\EBookingDomain\EBookingDomain.xproj" (Rebuild destinos) -- ERROR. El proyecto "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (1) est  compilando "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\EBookingRepository\EBookingRepository.xproj" (7) en el nodo 1 (Rebuild destinos). C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\EBookingRepository\EBookingRepository.xproj(8,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco. Compilaci¢n del proyecto terminada "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\EBookingRepository\EBookingRepository.xproj" (Rebuild destinos) -- ERROR. El proyecto "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (1) est  compilando "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\CommonUI\CommonUI.xproj" (8) en el nodo 1 (Rebuild destinos). C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\CommonUI\CommonUI.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco. Compilaci¢n del proyecto terminada "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\CommonUI\CommonUI.xproj" (Rebuild destinos) -- ERROR. El proyecto "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (1) est  compilando "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\CommonLibrary\CommonLibrary.xproj" (9) en el nodo 1 (Rebuild destinos). C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\CommonLibrary\CommonLibrary.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco. Compilaci¢n del proyecto terminada "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\CommonLibrary\CommonLibrary.xproj" (Rebuild destinos) -- ERROR. El proyecto "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (1) est  compilando "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\Expedia\Expedia.xproj" (10) en el nodo 1 (Rebuild destinos). C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\Expedia\Expedia.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco. Compilaci¢n del proyecto terminada "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\Expedia\Expedia.xproj" (Rebuild destinos) -- ERROR. El proyecto "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (1) est  compilando "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\ExpediaDomain\ExpediaDomain.xproj" (11) en el nodo 1 (Rebuild destinos). C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\ExpediaDomain\ExpediaDomain.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco. Compilaci¢n del proyecto terminada "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\ExpediaDomain\ExpediaDomain.xproj" (Rebuild destinos) -- ERROR. El proyecto "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (1) est  compilando "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\Nps\Nps.xproj" (12) en el nodo 1 (Rebuild destinos). C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\Nps\Nps.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco. Compilaci¢n del proyecto terminada "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\Nps\Nps.xproj" (Rebuild destinos) -- ERROR. El proyecto "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (1) est  compilando "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\NpsDomain\NpsDomain.xproj" (13) en el nodo 1 (Rebuild destinos). C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\NpsDomain\NpsDomain.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco. Compilaci¢n del proyecto terminada "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\NpsDomain\NpsDomain.xproj" (Rebuild destinos) -- ERROR. El proyecto "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (1) est  compilando "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\ExpediaRepository\ExpediaRepository.xproj" (14) en el nodo 1 (Rebuild destinos). C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\ExpediaRepository\ExpediaRepository.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco. Compilaci¢n del proyecto terminada "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\ExpediaRepository\ExpediaRepository.xproj" (Rebuild destinos) -- ERROR. El proyecto "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (1) est  compilando "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\B2C\B2C.xproj" (15) en el nodo 1 (Rebuild destinos). C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\B2C\B2C.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco. Compilaci¢n del proyecto terminada "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\B2C\B2C.xproj" (Rebuild destinos) -- ERROR. El proyecto "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (1) est  compilando "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\BackOffice\BackOffice.xproj" (16) en el nodo 1 (Rebuild destinos). C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\BackOffice\BackOffice.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco. Compilaci¢n del proyecto terminada "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\BackOffice\BackOffice.xproj" (Rebuild destinos) -- ERROR. El proyecto "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (1) est  compilando "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\CMSRepository\CMSRepository.xproj" (17) en el nodo 1 (Rebuild destinos). C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\CMSRepository\CMSRepository.xproj(8,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco. Compilaci¢n del proyecto terminada "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\CMSRepository\CMSRepository.xproj" (Rebuild destinos) -- ERROR. El proyecto "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (1) est  compilando "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\CMSDomain\CMSDomain.xproj" (18) en el nodo 1 (Rebuild destinos). C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\CMSDomain\CMSDomain.xproj(8,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco. Compilaci¢n del proyecto terminada "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\CMSDomain\CMSDomain.xproj" (Rebuild destinos) -- ERROR. El proyecto "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (1) est  compilando "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\Test\Test.xproj" (19) en el nodo 1 (Rebuild destinos). C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\Test\Test.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco. Compilaci¢n del proyecto terminada "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\Test\Test.xproj" (Rebuild destinos) -- ERROR. El proyecto "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (1) est  compilando "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\Exceptions\Exceptions.xproj" (20) en el nodo 1 (Rebuild destinos). C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\Exceptions\Exceptions.xproj(8,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco. Compilaci¢n del proyecto terminada "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\Exceptions\Exceptions.xproj" (Rebuild destinos) -- ERROR. El proyecto "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (1) est  compilando "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\WebApi\WebApi.xproj" (21) en el nodo 1 (Rebuild destinos). C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\WebApi\WebApi.xproj(8,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco. Compilaci¢n del proyecto terminada "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\WebApi\WebApi.xproj" (Rebuild destinos) -- ERROR. Compilaci¢n del proyecto terminada "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (rebuild destinos) -- ERROR.

ERROR al compilar.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (rebuild destino) (1) -> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\MongoRepository\MongoRepository.xproj" (Rebuild destino) (2) ->   C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\MongoRepository\MongoRepository.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco.


"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (rebuild destino) (1) -> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\MongoDomain\MongoDomain.xproj" (Rebuild destino) (3) ->   C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\MongoDomain\MongoDomain.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco.


"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (rebuild destino) (1) -> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\EBookingCoreNew\EBookingCoreNew.xproj" (Rebuild destino) (4) ->   C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\EBookingCoreNew\EBookingCoreNew.xproj(8,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco.


"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (rebuild destino) (1) -> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\NPSRepository\NPSRepository.xproj" (Rebuild destino) (5) ->   C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\NPSRepository\NPSRepository.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco.


"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (rebuild destino) (1) -> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\EBookingDomain\EBookingDomain.xproj" (Rebuild destino) (6) ->   C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\EBookingDomain\EBookingDomain.xproj(8,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco.


"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (rebuild destino) (1) -> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\EBookingRepository\EBookingRepository.xproj" (Rebuild destino) (7) ->   C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\EBookingRepository\EBookingRepository.xproj(8,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco.


"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (rebuild destino) (1) -> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\CommonUI\CommonUI.xproj" (Rebuild destino) (8) ->   C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\CommonUI\CommonUI.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco.


"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (rebuild destino) (1) -> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\CommonLibrary\CommonLibrary.xproj" (Rebuild destino) (9) ->   C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\CommonLibrary\CommonLibrary.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco.


"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (rebuild destino) (1) -> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\Expedia\Expedia.xproj" (Rebuild destino) (10) ->   C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\Expedia\Expedia.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco.


"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (rebuild destino) (1) -> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\ExpediaDomain\ExpediaDomain.xproj" (Rebuild destino) (11) ->   C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\ExpediaDomain\ExpediaDomain.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco.


"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (rebuild destino) (1) -> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\Nps\Nps.xproj" (Rebuild destino) (12) ->   C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\Nps\Nps.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco.


"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (rebuild destino) (1) -> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\NpsDomain\NpsDomain.xproj" (Rebuild destino) (13) ->   C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\NpsDomain\NpsDomain.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco.


"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (rebuild destino) (1) -> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\ExpediaRepository\ExpediaRepository.xproj" (Rebuild destino) (14) ->   C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\ExpediaRepository\ExpediaRepository.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco.


"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (rebuild destino) (1) -> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\B2C\B2C.xproj" (Rebuild destino) (15) ->   C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\B2C\B2C.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco.


"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (rebuild destino) (1) -> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\BackOffice\BackOffice.xproj" (Rebuild destino) (16) ->   C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\BackOffice\BackOffice.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco.


"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (rebuild destino) (1) -> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\CMSRepository\CMSRepository.xproj" (Rebuild destino) (17) ->   C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\CMSRepository\CMSRepository.xproj(8,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco.


"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (rebuild destino) (1) -> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\CMSDomain\CMSDomain.xproj" (Rebuild destino) (18) ->   C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\CMSDomain\CMSDomain.xproj(8,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco.


"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (rebuild destino) (1) -> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\Test\Test.xproj" (Rebuild destino) (19) ->   C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\Test\Test.xproj(7,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco.


"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (rebuild destino) (1) -> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\Exceptions\Exceptions.xproj" (Rebuild destino) (20) ->   C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\Exceptions\Exceptions.xproj(8,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco.


"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\ebookingV4.sln" (rebuild destino) (1) -> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\WebApi\WebApi.xproj" (Rebuild destino) (21) ->   C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\eBookingV4\workspace\src\WebApi\WebApi.xproj(8,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props". Aseg£rese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaraci¢n <Import> es correcta y de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco.
```

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [External VS2013 build error "error MSB4019: The imported project <path> was not found"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718281/external-vs2013-build-error-error-msb4019-the-imported-project-path-was-not)

Comment: You could use tool like flubu to make things easier around build process. Mora about flubu on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40890522/choice-for-build-tool-msbuild-nant-or-something-else/42513062#42513062 Btw se examples for .net core. Answer is for .net

Comment: If it's a .Net Core project, why don't you use the dotnet cli and issue build commands like `dotnet build`?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do so using this simple groovy \ pipline + running unittests

So the final pipeline is:

```html
node {
stage 'Checkout'
    checkout scm

stage 'Build'
    bat "\"C:/Program Files/dotnet/dotnet.exe\" restore \"${workspace}/MyProg.sln\""
    bat "\"C:/Program Files/dotnet/dotnet.exe\" build \"${workspace}/MyProg.sln\""

stage 'UnitTests'
    bat returnStatus: true, script: "\"C:/Program Files/dotnet/dotnet.exe\" test \"${workspace}/MyProg.sln\" --logger \"trx;LogFileName=unit_tests.xml\" --no-build"
    step([$class: 'MSTestPublisher', testResultsFile:"**/unit_tests.xml", failOnError: true, keepLongStdio: true])
}
```

I have uploaded some examples that I made to my GitHub for everyone to use and contribute, feel free to take a look:

https://github.com/avrum/JenkinsFileFor.NETCore

Those pipline jenkinsfile will add this pipline template to your build:

[image: Example Jenkins Pipeline|Solid]