# MSBuild error when building the solution from VSTS build

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, azure-pipelines

I am getting the following error when I am building the solution using continuous integration

> ### [error]Apps\App.Service\App.Service.csproj(203,11):
>
> Error MSB4226: The imported project
> "$(VSToolsPath)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets" was not found.
> Also, tried to find
> "$(VSToolsPath)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets" in the fallback
> search path(s) for $(VSToolsPath) - "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0" . These search paths are
> defined in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe.Config". Confirm
> that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the
> file exists on disk in one of the search paths.

When I check my `.csproj` I have the following on top  `<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />` so can some one tell me what was the issue

Comment: What's your project and if it's migrate from vs2015 to vs2017? If you used local private agent to build, please also check the file `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets` is exist in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web`.

Comment: Hi I am having 4 projects which I am building out of that 1 is executing successfully with `msbuild` but the remaining are failing

Comment: What's the different settings among the four projects? Or can you share the four projects in one drive?

Comment: Able to figure out from here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/31756/msbuild-targets-not-found-for-project-created-in-v.html

Comment: @DorababuMeka if you were able to resolve this issue, can you please add your solution as an answer?

Comment: I didn't remember the solution as I am currently not working on PS but I did some thing from the link I posted

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when trying to setup gitlab CI on my project.
This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20095260/5873231 solved my problem. I leave it here, maybe it's useful for someone.