# Deploying asp.net 4.5 application on IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7.5, asp.net-4.5

I have a simple asp.net 4.5 application.
I've tried to deploy it on IIS 7.5 (win server 2008 R2), but it doesn't seem to work.

I wonder if it's possible to deploy it on IIS 7.5?

Comment: What error messages do you get? You'll need to give us more than that if you want some suggestions. Have you got .Net 4.5 installed on the server for a start?

Comment: Click this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057814/deploying-a-net-4-5-website-to-an-iis-7-5-server. Am sure it helps

Answer (score 1):

Thanks  @GrandMasterFlush, @Michael.
There just wasn't .net framework 4.5 installed on the machine that I was trying to deploy my project on.
After I asked administrators to install .net framework  4.5, it works fine.