# Is the .NET Framework 4.5 compatible with IIS7?

Tags: .net, iis, iis-7.5

Is the .NET Framework 4.5, and all the goodness it comes with, e.g. MVC4, compatible with IIS7? Or must it run on IIS 7.5?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559372/how-to-set-net-framework-4-5-version-in-iis-7-application-pool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET Framework 4.5 is a super set of the 4.0 Framework.  Yes, it will work with IIS 7.5 and should you configure your app pools to use 4.