# ideal .net version to use in an application pool with an application created to use .net 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a web application on Visual Studio 2013 Update 1 with MVC5 ASP.NET. The application is using Identity Authentication. I have tried to launch it on the server in a .netV4.0 Application pool but it keeps giving me an error. I had read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559372/how-to-set-net-framework-4-5-version-in-iis-7-application-pool) post that it doesnt matter if your app points to 4.5 and you run it in a 4.0 application pool. But as stated in one of the comments in the post by Gene Reddick my async calls fail as well. My main questions now are:

- if I will need to upgrade the .net version in my server
- How it might affect other applications and,
- how to go about installing the new version in the server to be used by a particular application pool, if not in the normal way

Prompt Answers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what exactly is the error reported? What does the event viewer and your logging say?

Comment: I am using identity for logins. When i add the application in IIS, I am able to view my home page and the login page but once I try to login, i get the error `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.
)`

Comment: Are you absolutely certain it is due to the .Net Framework version? Is the database reachable? Try to do an ODBC test to confirm connectivity.

Comment: Hi, It is an ODBC error. Still haven't been able to solve it. All my connections are working but i still seem to not get rid of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like your link to another SO answer says, there is no .Net 4.5 app pool in IIS. Instead, any version of .Net 4.x shows up as the .Net 4.0 app pool because all versions of .Net 4.5.x are really just upgrades to .Net 4.0. There is not distinction between the two, and you can't have both installed separately.

In order to know if you have .Net 4.5 installed, you may use a tool such as [Asoft .Net Version Detector](http://www.asoft.be/prod_netver.html) or [look in the registry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/199783/2646868). If you are running on Windows Server 2012/Windows 8 or newer, you already have .Net 4.5. If not, you can upgrade to the latest [.Net 4.5.2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42643). Note that the installer for .Net 4.5.2 does apply to Server 2012/Windows 8+ since those versions of Windows only come with .Net 4.5.0.

Once you have the newer .Net CLR installed, your app pool should just work with no further configuration.