# VS 2012 Not pointing the asp.Net framework to 4.0 but .net framework does point to 4.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012

I am using VS 2012 editor for my application and my targeting framework is 4.0 version. I installed the 4.5 framework as well. When I run the application the asp.net framework version is not pointing to 4.0. Its always pointing to 4.5, But .Net framework is pointing to 4.0. I have tried my level best to change it in application settings. But It doesn't changed it.

This is how it looks like

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.5.27.0

Could any one please help me out to fix this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set .net Framework 4.5 version in IIS 7 application pool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559372/how-to-set-net-framework-4-5-version-in-iis-7-application-pool)

Comment: No, I am running in my local machine.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific... HOW are you trying to change your settings... What isn't working exactly?  You do know that .NET 4.5 runs on the .NET 4.0 runtime, correct?

Comment: I changed the project properties and pointed my project to target 4.0 Framework. Exactly Right Click On Project ->Properties->Application->Target Framework to 4.0,this is how i changed my project settings. When an error occurred I figured out the below information.                            Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.5.27.0.   Here i want the asp.net version also to point out 4.0.