# How To Know If Running ASP.Net 4.5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I'm trying to get the asp:FileUpload control to work with multiple files and I can't seem to get it to work.  It also doesn't recognize HasFiles and PostedFiles in my code behind.

So on the server I check the installed programs and I see "Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5.2.  But in the folder where my application exists the only options for the application pool are;

```
DefaultAppPool
Classic .Net AppPool
MSSharePointAppPool
ASP.NET v4.0
ASP.NET v4.0 Classic
```

It's set to ASP.NET v4.0

Sorry to be dense but how do I change or make sure that it's using ASP.NET 4.5 so that the file upload will work properly with multiple files?

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't make a difference in the functionality of your program, as .NET 4.5 is just an update for 4.0.  See here

[How to set .net Framework 4.5 version in IIS 7 application pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559372/how-to-set-net-framework-4-5-version-in-iis-7-application-pool)